# SharePoint AADSTS65001 DelegationDoesNotExist - The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID X

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise

I’m using office365-rest-python-client to programmatically access a SharePoint site in Office365 online.

The application I’m acceding  it from , is just a backend app in python
 For that I went to https://entra.microsoft.com/ admin center and did the following:

1. - Create an app in Applications > App Registration
2. - Added a Secret to that application
3. - Granted Permission to that application to access SharePoint API
4. - Granted admin consent

Then using office365-rest-python-client , I used the application clientId and the SecretValue to send a request to add a page

The request fails with the following error showing in the Audit Logs in Microsoft Office365 Entra

```
- Based on the information you provided we have identified following issue and recommend taking the action to resolve the issue.
- Error Code: 65001
- Message: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID ''(). Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.

More details in the docs show:

AADSTS65001 DelegationDoesNotExist - The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID X. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.
```

The client side shows

```
“POST /sites/security/_api/contextInfo” 

and 

“POST /sites/security/_api/sitePages/pages    


401 client error  “Unauthorized for url  https://my-sharepoint/sites/security/_api/sitePages/pages
```

What could be the cause of this issue ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Form the documentation came the solution.
https://pypi.org/project/Office365-REST-Python-Client/

Needed certificate auth

3. Using an Azure AD application (certificate credentials flow)

Documentation:

```
Granting access via Azure AD App-Only
wiki
```

Example: connect_with_client_certificate.py